Number of graphs with only one fully connected vertex
Let $n$ be the number of vertices in the graph. Loops and multiple edges are forbidden. The vertices are numbered. How many graphs are there on $n$ vertices such that only one vertex is connected to all the others?
Examples: for $n = 1$ there's only one possible graph with one vertex and zero edges. For $n = 2$, there are no graphs satisfying the condition as both vertices have the same number of edges when connected. For $n = 3$, there're $3$ possible variants: $2 — 1 — 3$, $1 — 2 — 3$, and $1 — 3 — 2$. For $n = 4$, there're $16$ possible variants (two configurations, either having three or four edges).
Here are answers for the first eight $n$ received by brute force script:
$$1 \rightarrow 1 \\ 2 \rightarrow 0 \\ 3 \rightarrow 3 \\ 4 \rightarrow 16 \\ 5 \rightarrow 205 \\ 6 \rightarrow 4608 \\ 7 \rightarrow 192143 \\ 8 \rightarrow 15098272$$

it's the same as asking "how many graphs with $n-1$ nodes have no fully connected nodes" and then multiply by $n$

Fom https://oeis.org/A006129 and a bit of counting, I think
$a(n) = n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{(n-1)-k} \binom{n-1}{k}2^{\binom{k}{2}}$ is as good as you can get.

@Jack seems you're right, thank you!
